# How can I use Ctrl+c and ctrl+v in nattable?

Tags: nattable

Issue:-

I am able to create copy command and paste command but I want to know how I can use it with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> in nat table.

I have tried keylistner but it send nullpointer exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to copy and paste inside a NatTable you should use the corresponding commands and command handlers.

To copy data you need to bind the `CopyDataAction` to the requested key combination. This executes the `CopyDataToClipboardCommand` to copy the data to the clipboard. The action is registered by default for CTRL+C in the [DefaultSelectionBindings](https://github.com/eclipse/nebula.widgets.nattable/blob/master/org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.core/src/org/eclipse/nebula/widgets/nattable/selection/config/DefaultSelectionBindings.java).

For pasting copied data you need to execute the [PasteDataCommand](https://github.com/eclipse/nebula.widgets.nattable/blob/master/org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.core/src/org/eclipse/nebula/widgets/nattable/copy/command/PasteDataCommand.java). This was introduced with [NatTable 1.4](http://www.eclipse.org/nattable/nandn/nandn_140.php)

To make this work some additional configurations need to be done, e.g. the configuration of an alternative `CopyDataCommandHandler` that uses the `InternalCellClipboard` and the configuration of the necessary key bindings. An example can be seen in [DefaultFormulaConfiguration](https://github.com/eclipse/nebula.widgets.nattable/blob/master/org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.core/src/org/eclipse/nebula/widgets/nattable/formula/config/DefaultFormulaConfiguration.java) where the configurations are done for formula support.

Comment: I know the copy command and i am using that but i am not able to find paste command for nattable till now.

Comment: The PasteDataCommand was introduced with NatTable 1.4. I updated the answer to give some more information.

Comment: Hi Dirk, Thanks for reply.... I have used below command for pasting the data in my naatable but does not work ....copy is working finr though

Comment: NatTable natTable = this.getTable();
        natTable.doCommand(new PasteDataCommand(natTable.getConfigRegistry()));

Comment: As said in the answer you need to register the InternalPasteCommandHandler and the InternalCopyCommandHandler to make it work. It does not work by default!

Comment: Hi Dirk, Copy paste is working for the same sheet but i am not able to paste the data when i am trying to paste it in different sheet.Do you have any suggestion ?

Comment: In that case you need to implement a paste command handler yourself that is able to interprete what is in the clipboard or implement some sort of shared InternalCellClipboard.